# WinRT CopyAsync file. How do i know when it ended?

Tags: asynchronous, windows-runtime

I have a Win8 app that needs to use a Sqlite DB; every time that the app starts i check that file exists, if not exists i try to copy it.
The problem is that when i copy it the app tries to open it before the copy ended and i get an error:

I call the following function and then try to query the database:

```
public async static void CopyDatabase()
    {
        bool isExisting = false;
        try
        {
            StorageFile storage = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("dbname.db");
            isExisting = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isExisting = false;
        }
        if (!isExisting)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("dbname.db");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);

        }

    }
```

How can i know when the copy is ended? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that the issue is in this method's code, but in how you call it.

Change your method's declaration to:

```
public async static Task CopyDatabase()
```

And call it using:

```
await CopyDatabase();
```

This will guarantee that the copy is completed before your next line of code (which probably tries to open the database) is executed.